# Send a notification only when my app is not running

Tags: android, receiver

I want to send a notification when an alarm starts the broadcastreceiver and my App is closed. On the Receive method, Works fine detecting when the app is running. But the else part is not working. The "send_notification" method only works if it is not inside the else. Even the System.Out is not working when app is closed.

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


      if (App_status.isAppRunning(context, "com.example.app")) {

            System.out.println(TAG + " APP IS RUNNING");

      } else {

            System.out.println(TAG + " APP IS NOT RUNNING");

        send_notification(context);

      }
}
```

```
    public static boolean isAppRunning(final Context context, final String packageName) {
        final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (procInfos != null) {
            for (final ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : procInfos) {
                if (processInfo.processName.equals(packageName)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Why doesn't work the else part?

I tried also to create a String variable. Being null at the begining the activity and changing to "no" if app is running. Inside  the if(App_status.isAppRunning(context, "com.example.app")).

So at the end asking if the variable is diferent of no send the notification. But also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use alarm manager, for this :

```
AlarmManager alarmManager =
    (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getService(context, requestId, intent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
if (pendingIntent != null && alarmManager != null) {
  alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

For full guidance visit this [developer android page](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#java)

Comment: yes I'm doing this to bring my app to my Broadcastreceiver. But this is not my question. 

The question is to know if my app is running in the moment of the alarm is triggered.
So, if it is not running I want to send a notification to the user.

Comment: You don't need to figure it out, just se the alarm manager at a time of your choosing, and the whether the app is running or not, it will notify the user.